# H2 Database WIth .NET Application

Tags: java, .net, database, h2

I have created .NET APP that is supposed queries the H2 DB but at the time of **"DriverManager.getConnection(DBUrl, DBUName, DBPassword);"**
it gives the following error:

---

Error : IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\test.lock.db' is denied."; "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\test.lock.db

I have accessed the H2 DB throught its console its working fine but when i try to connect it with .NET App it gives above error.

**Edited:**
http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#microsoft_dot_net

I'm using this approach to query H2 database.

Comment: What is your DBUrl? If it's jdbc:h2:test, then see http://h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files - I suggest to use an absolute path or relative to the user home directory instead, such as jdbc:h2:~/test

Comment: thanks, that exactly was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete **test.lock.db** file

Comment: there isn't any. the folder don't even exist.

Comment: i have win7 if that helps in any way.

Comment: Do you use JDBC or ADO.NET? If you use JDBC, try to append the following command to your JDBC connection string `jdbc:h2:<url>;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`